# Can we do something about sites copying content from Super User? — Redux

Tags: discussion

[Nixphoe asked a while ago:](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3470/can-we-do-something-about-sites-copying-content-from-super-user)

> I know this isn't ethical, but is there anything we can do about other sites copying from SU?
>
> [Any information about the AsyncMapLite Trojan?](https://superuser.com/questions/321635/any-information-about-the-asyncmaplite-trojan/321665#321665)
>
> http://answerleaks.com/any-information-asyncmaplite-trojan/superuser/321635

---

Unfortunately, all responses in that topic assume that the site in question adheres to the CC license rules governing the Stack sites' content. The user even accepted one of these answers.

**This is wrong**. The site in question *does not attribute answers* to their authors. They seem to copy very few answers, so it's difficult to find examples of wrongdoing — [here's](http://answerleaks.com/how-to-clean-up-this-malware-ldquo-apibilil-dll-rdquo-on-windows-7/superuser/198149) one though, archived below. While it states who asked, and links to the user's profile, it does not credit the authors of the answers.

> [image]

---

So, again: **Is there anything we can do about other sites copying from SU?**

Comment: I will gladly see this topic closed/deleted if someone has a good idea on how to revive the other topic and remove bad information from it.

Comment: Could've set a bounty, probably, if it was still open? But I like your approach better anyway :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abby from the Chaos team has [**a list available**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/106824#106824) to report all sites not meeting the attribution requirements on Meta StackOverlow. From the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108139/what-is-www-qickfix-com-and-why-do-they-have-copies-of-so-data/108335#108335)

> We keep a running list of sites we have discovered to be in violation of the license [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers). I've added this new offender to my personal list of offenses to look into.
>
> Often, sites using Stack Overflow content are simply not aware of the infringement and they bring their sites up to snuff promptly as soon as I send them a message pointing it out. Sometimes... they don't. But that's another story.

Comment: I added answerleaks.com to that list.

Comment: Noted. Thanks, friends!